# Event Email received as attachment, not as a request to add to calendar

Tags: java, html-email, email-attachments

**This is my send mail function. which is used to send a mail to an email address, The mail contains an event which can be added to the clients calendar by clicking the Yes button in the Email.**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ValidationException {
            List<String> to= new ArrayList<String>();
            String subject="";
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            StringBuffer buffer = sb.append("BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" +
                    "PRODID:Zimbra-Calendar-Provider\n" +
                    "VERSION:2.0\n" +
                    "METHOD:REQUEST\n" +
                    "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\n" +
                    "TZID:Asia/Kolkata\n" +
                    "BEGIN:STANDARD\n" +
                    "DTSTART:16010101T000000\n" +
                    "TZOFFSETTO:+0530\n" +
                    "TZOFFSETFROM:+0530\n" +
                    "TZNAME:IST\n" +
                    "END:STANDARD\n" +
                    "END:VTIMEZONE\n" +
                    "BEGIN:VEVENT\n" +
                    "UID:06d8d851-e665-4930-a18c-3d60dbaed6e4\n" +
                    "SUMMARY:Test\n" +
                    "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:mailto"+
                    " @ac.us\n" +
                    "ORGANIZER;CN=Vinay Kumar:mailto:orgnizar@ej.com\n" +
                    "DTSTART;TZID='Asia/Kolkata':20140306T120000\n" +
                    "DTEND;TZID='Asia/Kolkata':20140306T130000\n" +
                    "STATUS:CONFIRMED\n" +
                    "CLASS:PUBLIC\n" +
                    "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY\n" +
                    "TRANSP:OPAQUE\n" +
                    "LAST-MODIFIED:20140306T123110Z\n" +
                    "DTSTAMP:20140306T123110Z\n" +
                    "SEQUENCE:0\n" +
                    "DESCRIPTION:The following is a new meeting request:\n\nSubject: Test \nOrgan"+
                    " izer: orgnizar <orgnizar@ej.com> \n\nTime: Thursday'\', March 6'\',"+
                    "  2014'\', 12:00:00 PM - 1:00:00 PM GMT +05:30 Chennai'\', Kolkata'\', Mumbai'\', New"+
                    "  Delhi\n \nInvitees: dg@ac.us \n\n\n*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*\n\nTest\n" +
                    "BEGIN:VALARM\n" +
                    "ACTION:DISPLAY\n" +
                    "TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT5M\n" +
                    "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\n" +
                    "END:VALARM\n" +
                    "END:VEVENT\n" +
                    "END:VCALENDAR);\n");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(
                                userName, password);
                    }
                });
        session.setDebug(sessionDebug);
        try {

                Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
                Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                msg.addHeader("method","REQUEST");
                msg.addHeader("component","VEVENT");
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("orgnizar@ej.com"));//emailConfig.getFromEmail()));
                msg.setReplyTo(new javax.mail.Address[] { new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress("vj@ej.com")});//emailConfig.getReplyTo()) });
                msg.setSubject("Outlook Meeting Request Using JavaMail");
                boolean first=true;
                String result="";
                    msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
                    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
                BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                    // Fill the message 
                    messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "7bit");
    //              messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-ID","calendar_message");
                    messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Type","text/calendar");
                    messageBodyPart.addHeader("charset","UTF-8");
                    messageBodyPart.addHeader("method","REQUEST");
                    messageBodyPart.setFileName("sss.ics");
                    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
                    new ByteArrayDataSource(buffer.toString(), "text/calendar")));//very important
                    multiPart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                    msg.setContent(multiPart);

                    /*DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(buffer.toString(), "application/x-any");
                    msg.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));*/
                    Transport.send(msg);
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }

        } catch (MessagingException mex) {

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        finally{
            session=null;
        }
```

Currently, I am receiving an email with an `.ics` file as attachment and i need that as an event which can be directly added to the calendar by clicking an Yes.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile (due to the line starting with "charset=utf-8". And it's not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: sorry that was an unnecessary line

Comment: @FlorentBayle I am asking to send an email with an event attached to it.!! Currently i am able to send the mail but the ics file is shown as an attachment.!! The Mail server is not detecting it as an event mail

Comment: Do you have a solution for this ?